# An increasing function on [0,1] that is not continuous with increasing subsequence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an increasing function that is not continuous. Show that for any sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $[0,1]$ there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$ of it such that $(f(x_{n_k}))_k$ converges.

Let $(x_n)_n \subset [0,1]$. If $x_n=x \in [0,1]$, i.e, constant for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then the result follows. Clearly $0 \leq x_n \leq 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k \subset (x_n)_n$ such that $(x_{n_k})_k$ converges. Now what we know is that $ [0,1]\supset(x_{n_k})_k$ converges, so how that can help me to prove the convergence of its image.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Since $f$ is increasing, we have $f(0)\leq f(x_n)\leq f(1)$, so $\{f(x_n)\}_n$ is a bounded sequence

Comment: Thank you so much, sometimes thinking too hard takes you away from the solution

Comment: @lc2r43, maybe add your comment as an answer.

Comment: @pmun The domain of $f(x) = -\frac{1}{x}$ is not $[0,1]$.

Comment: @pmun note your function is not defined at 0. How can you define $f(0)$ to make $f$ increasing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is increasing, we have $f(0)\leq f(x_n)\leq f(1)$, so $\{f(x_n)\}_n$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers. By Bolzano-Weierstrass, we conclude that $\{f(x_n)\}_n$ has a convergent subsequence.